# Changing textBox size dynamically - issue with Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText

Tags: vb.net

So I want to start with a small textbox and expand it as necessary.
However the Font I am passing (textBoxComment.Font) produces an syntax error and I can't compile the code. 
*"value of fontinfo cannot be converted to system.drawing.font vb.net"*

Is there way to fix this?

```
Private Sub textBoxComment_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim size As Size = Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBoxComment.Text, textBoxComment.Font)
    textBoxComment.Width = size.Width
    textBoxComment.Height = size.Height
End Sub
```

Using VS-2010, targeting .Net 4.0 Framework

Comment: That code shouldn't cause that error. But you are missing things like allowing for padding and margins, and do you really intend to resize the control for each keystroke?

Comment: What kind of font is the TextBox using?  Your posted code does not create an error for us.

Comment: `fontinfo` is a WebControls Type

Comment: The type of textbox is: Just a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox

Comment: I don't plan on re sizing until it is over the default length, but just trying to get the basic functionality down.

Comment: can you get size of font any other way?